Whats the name of this Sci-Fi Movie? Space prison / deathrow and hacking bug ? cyberpunk
Can someone name this movie/tv episode maybe?
Recalling from memory (could be multiple movies linked together? highly doubt it though all fits right)
There's a prison death row in a space ship, with people waiting in line to have their organs (liver and heart?) cut out. The organs go down a chute where there are tons of organs; I believe a big worm-like bug ate them. The movie's main character was a man, I think, and looked very primitive in that age compared to everyone else, but was in fact the smartest person there. There was also in jail someone waiting to get into the death row line who had a bug capable of artificial intelligence and a little laser/cutting tool to disable the prison doors. Women who are ugly or fat get a punishment to become beautiful prostitutes with an uploaded personality that is very basic and dumb. The robot who does the surgeries gets gets his head cut off and becomes a pet.
I think the main character was of a rare alien race, only one or two of its kind, and was trying to escape. That's how the movie probably begins.

why did I get downvoted? that's all I recall from memory I don't remember the year of this movie but it felt before HD was invented.

Probably because there isn't a lot to go on and what you did leave is rather incoherent.

I detailed it pretty well, just proofread it again, I think there is only one movie that could have all this in it. Alright I fixed it up the main character was a primitive looking character compared to the others in that age. Probably cowboy but not 100% sure about that one.

@SSpoke So, the comment I down-voted you for has been removed (either by a mod or you). However, now you're using foul language in these comments. The down-vote stays. If you'll delete the offensive comment (or remove the foul language) I'll be happy to remove my down-vote. All (we) I ask is some semblance of professional, or at least G-rated behavior.

Also, I personally dislike identify-this-X questions, but this one is actually one of the better written examples. There appears to be plenty of details allowing someone to do the ID (and in fact, did.)

That is definitely the first episode of the Lexx series, (1997-2002), even though the Wikipedia entry doesn't include a lot of the exposition.  It started off as four 90-minute movies.  The guy with the laser-cutter dragonfly was played by Barry Bostwick, of Rocky Horror fame.  It's on Youtube.
